# Haskell `elem` in nested list

Tags: list, haskell, nested

I want to check for an element in a nested list.

I already tried several ways but I will always get the wrong result or some errors.

```
[X] `elem` [[X,X,X],[O,O,O]]
```

returns False but should be True

```
X `elem` [[X,X,X],[O,O,O]]
```

throws a error, that types can not be matched.

Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements of the list are sublists, and there is no `[X]` sublist in the list.

You can check if any of the elements of the sublists contain `X` with:

```
any (elem X) [[X, X, X], [O, O, O]]
```

or with `elem` as infix operator:

```
any (X `elem`) [[X, X, X], [O, O, O]]
```

but these are semantically completely identical.

These will check if for *any* of the sublists (here `[X, X, X]` and `[O, O, O]`), `X` is an element of these lists.

Another option, as [@amalloy described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402678/haskell-elem-in-nested-list/70402698?noredirect=1#comment124450564_70402698) is to concatenate all the sublists into a list, and then perform an `elem` check on these, so:

```
elem X (concat [[X, X, X], [O, O, O]])
```

Comment: Alternatively, `elem X (concat xs)`.